# Django: Subclassing models.CharField to convert values before saving to/after loading from the database

Tags: python, django, forms, custom-component, subclassing

I have a legacy database with encoding issues. I cannot fixing it without breaking a lot of stuff

But I still want to deal with it in my side django app (django 1.2)

I thought that subclassing CharField would be an awesome idea, so I did:

```
class EncCharField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        v = super(EncCharField, self).to_python(value)
        return v.encode('windows-1252').decode('windows-1251')
```

Firtst I though it worked, but then I ran into another issue

I use this model in `ModelForm` and `form.save`, when it creates a model instance from form instance, calls `EncCharField.to_python` again, but this time with `value` encoded properly, so my encoding-decoding throws an exception and all dies

So. Is there any way to distinguish situations when models in initialized from DB vs from Form (or other *valid* object)?

And the second question, how to re-encode back (`encode('windows-1251').decode('windows-1252')`) prior to saving into the database?